# When I call the function it shows nothing?

Tags: python-3.x

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

This is my script in python 3.5:

```
def plin1():
    for i in range(1000,1):
        for j in range(1000,1):
            if str(i*j)==str(i*j)[::-1]:
                break
            return i*j
        print(i,'*',j,'=',i*j)
```

But when I call this function, nothing is printed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object`

`range()` requires the first argument to be less than the second when `step` is positive, and `step` defaults to 1 when `range()` is called with 2 arguments. Hence the range object yields an empty sequence and the body of the for loop is never entered:

```
>>> list(range(1000, 1))
[]
```

However, by specifying a negative value for `step`, you can get the sequence that you require e.g.:

```
>>> list(range(10, 1))
[]
>>> list(range(10, 1, -1))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

So in your case you would do this:

```
for i in range(999, 99, -1):
    for j in range(999, 99, -1):
        # etc...
```

which would then iterate over all 3 digit numbers starting at the largest.

Also the use of `return` is incorrect and it will cause the function to terminate without printing anything. Here is a corrected version:

```
def plin1():
    for i in range(999, 99, -1):
        for j in range(999, 99, -1):
            if str(i*j) == str(i*j)[::-1]:
                return i*j
            print(i,'*',j,'=',i*j)
```

Now the function returns the value only when it finds a palindrome. If there were no palindromes, the function would return `None`.

---

Notice, however, that this does not produce the largest palindrome that is the product of two 3 digit numbers. This function returns 580085 which is 995 * 583. But the largest one is 993 * 913 = 906609. You need to figure out which is the largest palindrome across all products, not just the first palindrome found. Here is a generator expression that will produce the required result:

```
max((i*j,i,j) for i in range(100, 1000) for j in range(100, 1000)
        if str(i*j) == str(i*j)[::-1])
```

Which produces the tuple `(906609, 993, 913)`.

Probably there are optimisations that could be made to reduce the number of calculations.

Comment: Thank you for the information . After I fixed the range still don't why the output is always 1000000(one million) could you please tell me why?

Comment: @hamzabouabid:  the reason is the function returns immediately because of the placement of the `return` statement. See updated answer for suggested correction.

Comment: @hamzabouabid: also notice that `range()` includes the first argument in the result and excludes the second. Thus you need to range from 999 to 99 to cover all 3 digit numbers, and you don't need to process numbers below 100.

Answer (score 0):

`range` with two arguments `i`, `j` generates the range from `i` to `j`. If `i > j` then there is no range to generate, and when iterating over that range nothing happens.

Range also takes a "step" parameter, allowing you to set the increment of the range. Perhaps you meant to use that. It would look like this:

```
for i in range(1, 1000, 1):
    # loop body
```

Note that specifying a step of 1 is redundant, as 1 is the default value for that parameter.

If you want to generate a "do the right thing" range to generate the range from the lesser of (i, j) to the greater, you might write a function like the following:

```
def dwim_range(i,j):
    return range(*sorted((i,j)))
```

Here you're sorting the tuple `(i, j)` and then unpacking it with the `*` operator so that `range` gets the two items of the tuple, in sorted order.

Comment: is there a way to generate the range from j to i if j>i I mean theat I want that the check starts from the end.

Comment: @hamzabouabid Sure, see edited post for a suggestion on one way you might do this.